# Java install - Doesn't run the classes

Tags: java, windows, windows-8

I'm getting started with java development. So, I installed JRE and JDK in my computer.

Then, I created a simple Example.java file and saved it in my Desktop.
In the prompt, I executed

`javac Example.java`

and it worked ok. A `.class` file has been created in my Desktop.

Then, I tried to run the class, executing this:

`java Example`

and I got an error in a window alert, with this message:

```
Java Installation Not Completed
Unable to install Java
There are error in the command line switches: "Example";.
Check that the commands are valid and try again
```

Then, for testing, I executed both commands:
`javac -version` and
`java -version`. Both are installed in my computer.

What am I doing wrong?

I am running Windows 8 and have already set my environment variables.

Example.java:

```
public class Example {   
  public static void main(String args[]) {    
    System.out.println("Finally Java");  
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I tried many times

Comment: did you use offline installer? or online installer? It is recommended to use offline installer. http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1722.xml

Comment: What is inside your Example.java file? Just for clarification, edit your question and past the content of that file there.

Comment: Yes, Windows 8 64-bit

Comment: File should have the same name as a public class, it should not possibly compile, there is already a problem on compilation phase. Try to rename class or file so they will be the same and try again and let us know if anything changed.

Comment: The class is names Exemplo01 while your file is names Example. Correct that.

Comment: I'm sorry. I fixed above. Both have the same name. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove installation again, look for all leftovers and remove them manually, if you changed the directory you installed java to, remove environment variables as well and set them again. You should also make registry cleanup: https://java.com/en/download/help/manual_regedit.xml Make installation through offline installer.